# Cocoa: Zipping files

Tags: cocoa, zip

I'm stuck with creating and unzipping ZIP archives.

I have a list (an array) containing the filenames (including the full path information) of the files I need to archive. When the user wants the archive to be uncompressed the files shall be restored at their original location.

What I've tried so far:

- Used the "zip" command line tool (via NSTask): sometimes it throws a "Couldn't posix_spawn: error 7" error which I cannot resolve (maybe it has something to do with extended attributes (com.apple.quarantine - but sometimes it seems not to work on files / folders which do **not** have this attribute)
- Used the "tar" command line tool (via NSTask): same as with "zip" command line tool above
- Used *ZipKit* framework: This framework was able to compress and uncompress archives but it did not restore files at their original location
- *SSZipArchive*: An Objective-C class I've found during my researches. It is able to compress files but is not able to uncompress archives which has been created using this component

Any clue which might help is welcome.

I'm using the 2nd beta of Xcode 6.1 with Swift and my App is targeting 10.9 (Mavericks) and later.

Comment: SSZipArchive should be able to unzip it's zipped files, or is it one of the issues because of very big files or multithreaded code?

Comment: The code which was executing the uncompression is not multi-threaded. I think SSZipArchive has a problem with SymLinks (the "files" I tried to zip contained some of them). However, there's a problem with uncompressing the archive: SSZipArchive does not restore the files at their original location. Restoring the files to "/" (root directory) restored the files to "/".

Comment: I modified the code of SSZipArchive a bit. Now it is able to restore files at their original location. But there is still the issue with symbolic links: it seems like these cause SSZipArchive to run in an infinite loop (same with - empty - directories).